# Native app (ios/android) autentication using ADFS

Tags: android, ios, azure, identityserver3, adfs3.0

I basically want to want to authenticate with ADFS as an external identity provider in a native ios/android app. Preferably with a seamless login experience, but that may be asking to much.
The setup that I want is pretty much the one described [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/1166/aspnet-mvc-multiple-adfs-owin-katana) except that I moved the identity stuff to an STS project. The ios and android apps are accessing the web api.

I also used [this](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/oauth2-openid-connect-angular-aspdotnet) pluralsight course.

Now I "just" need a way to use the credentials received from the mobile app to issue an access token. 
I need to know if I am on the right path. I am using:

- IdentityServer3.
- Oauth2 and OpenID Connect. (using password grant)
- The solution has to work on adfs 3.0.
- NET 4.6 web api and mvc solutions running in azure.

I have been looking at the ADAL.NET project, but that seems to be primarily for Xamarin and I already have the ios and android developed natively.

Questions:

1. What is the best approach going forward?
2. Are there any (perhaps new) technologies that i am completely
   missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that with ADFS 3.0, there is no OpenID Connect support and very limited OAuth support - basically just auth. code grant for web API.

Much along [these lines](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/).

If you want the full stack (ala what you have with idsrv3), you need ADFS 4.0.

You could federate idsrv3 with ADFS using WS-Fed for the final hop.

Comment: Thank for your answer. When you say federate idsrv3 with ADFS using WS-Fed, do you mean using the Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation package and the UseWsFederationAuthentication or are you taking about doing setup on the ADFS server?

Comment: Both. iOS --> OIDC --> idsrv3 RP--> WS-Fed --> ADFS CP.